# SQL Row_number conditional

Tags: sql, sql-server, window-functions, partitioning

I need to row_number only Test_events in ('Math Test', 'Biology Test') in a separate column of my dataset with partitioning by student_id, session_id and ordering by Test_date asc, Test_order asc.

I tried to realize it in a column 'rnum' Code will be below. But I noticed that student 987 has incorrect rnum for 'Math Test' and 'Biology Test' there should be 1 and 2 rnum but I have 10 and 11. (for other students all correct).

How can I change my code to row_number only needed events in a separate column?

Needed numeration is in the column needed_rnum.
the dataset:

| student_id | Test_type | session_id | Test_date | Test_order | rnum | needed_rnum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 987 | First Test | 1 | 2022-05-01 23:47:46.000 | 0 | NULL | NULL |
| 987 | First Test | 1 | 2022-05-01 23:47:46.000 | 0 | NULL | NULL |
| 987 | Useful First Test | 1 | 2022-05-01 23:47:46.000 | 1 | NULL | NULL |
| 987 | Useful First Test | 1 | 2022-05-01 23:47:46.000 | 1 | NULL | NULL |
| 987 | Second Test | 1 | 2022-05-01 23:48:42.000 | 4 | NULL | NULL |
| 987 | Screening Test | NULL | 2022-05-01 23:48:50.000 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 987 | Second Test | 1 | 2022-05-01 23:55:53.000 | 4 | NULL | NULL |
| 987 | Screening Test | NULL | 2022-05-01 23:56:01.000 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 987 | History Test | 1 | 2022-05-01 23:56:39.347 | 11 | NULL | NULL |
| 987 | English Test | 1 | 2022-05-01 23:56:39.347 | 22 | NULL | NULL |
| 987 | Physics Test | 1 | 2022-05-01 23:56:39.347 | 32 | NULL | NULL |
| 987 | Math Test | 1 | 2022-05-01 23:56:43.080 | 50 | 10 | 1 |
| 987 | Biology Test | 1 | 2022-05-01 23:56:43.823 | 55 | 11 | 2 |
| 543 | Math Test | 1 | 2021-12-20 10:46:53.940 | 50 | 1 | 1 |
| 543 | Biology Test | 1 | 2021-12-20 11:19:54.173 | 55 | 2 | 2 |
| 543 | Marked A+ | 1 | 2021-12-21 13:17:33.100 | 500 | NULL | NULL |
| 543 | Math Test | 2 | 2021-12-21 13:36:50.357 | 50 | 1 | 1 |
| 543 | Biology Test | 2 | 2021-12-23 10:47:39.267 | 55 | 2 | 2 |
| 543 | Marked B+ | 2 | 2022-01-14 10:41:10.993 | 110 | NULL | NULL |
| 114 | Math Test | 1 | 2019-07-14 08:48:54.053 | 50 | 1 | 1 |
| 114 | Biology Test | NULL | 2019-07-14 08:49:33.807 | 55 | 1 | 1 |
| 114 | Biology Test | 1 | 2019-07-14 08:49:34.153 | 55 | 2 | 2 |
| 114 | Marked B+ | 1 | 2019-09-13 01:05:47.467 | 110 | NULL | NULL |

```
SELECT  student_id, 
        Test_type, 
        session_id, 
        Test_date, 
        Test_order, 
        
     ,case when Test_type in (
        'Math Test', 'Biology Test'
        ) THEN row_number()over (partition by student_id, session_id order by Test_date asc, Test_order asc) 
        else NULL end as rnum
FROM tab1 t
```

[image]
I am using MSSQL

Answer (score 1):

You need to also partition by whether `Test_type` is one of your values

```sql
SELECT
  student_id, 
  Test_type, 
  session_id, 
  Test_date, 
  Test_order, 
  case when Test_type in (
        'Math Test', 'Biology Test'
        ) THEN
    row_number() over (partition by student_id, session_id, case when Test_type in ('Math Test', 'Biology Test') then 0 else 1 end
                       order by Test_date, Test_order) 
  end as rnum
FROM tab1 t
```

Note that `ELSE NULL` is the default, as is `ASC`

Comment: Looks like that's not the case, it's partitioned only by `student_id` and `session_id`